# Side Nav Menu Question

Tags: php, jquery, css, xhtml

How can I have all my nested lists collapse and expand when clicked.

Here is my xHTML.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="some-link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="some-link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="some-link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure *exactly* what you're after, but the general concept looks like this:

```
$("li").click(function(e) {
  $(this).children('ul').toggle(400); //toggle the immediate child <ul>
  return false;  //stop the click from bubbling up, and the href working
});
```

​
[You can give it a try with your markup here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fFumX/2/).

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery plugin might be what you're looking for: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview

Your code will look something like this...

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/treeview/demo/screen.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/treeview/jquery.treeview.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/treeview/jquery.treeview.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example").treeview();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="example" class="filetree">
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="some-link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="some-link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="some-link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

There are different styles available depending on which class you call in your parent `<ul>` tag, so take a look at these demos and chose the one you like best: http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/treeview/demo/

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other ideas, I threw together something like this as a rough draft:

```
            $(".nav ul").hide();
            $(".nav li").click(function(){
                if ($(this).children("ul").length > 0) {
                    $(this).children("ul").toggle();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
```

In my example I added the class "nav" to the outer most ul to avoid conflicting with other possible uls on the page:

```
        <ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="some-link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="some-link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="some-link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="some-link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="some-link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Right - forgot I added a class to the outer most ul - see my update :-)